# how to pass json url response value one view controller to anotherviewcontroller using objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

passing response data from one class to another class

//i want to pass "reside:15" to another View controller.

```
2013-08-16 14:29:57.273 blabby[1432:1a603] Login response:{"response":"success","resid":15}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an class

```
Constant.h
```

in `constant.h`

take an string like

```
NSString *str;
```

import constant class into your class and than `str =your response data;`

and use it into another class.

Comment: That mean you recived {"response","success",userdid=15"} as a responce right???

Comment: {"response","success",userdid=15"} if you recived this as a response than first you have to split your response string and retrive your userid than put it into constant class string than it work fine for you

Comment: NSString *str = @"response","success",userdid=15";

NSArray *firstSplit = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSAssert(firstSplit.count == 2, @"Oops! Parsed string had more than one , no message or no numbers.");
NSString *msg = [firstSplit lastObject];
NSArray *numbers = [[firstSplit objectAtIndex:0] componentsSepratedByString:@","];

// print out the numbers (as strings)
for(NSString *currentNumberString in number) {
  NSLog(@"Number: %@", currentNumberString);
}

Comment: dude do one thing if your user athentication is success than take your responce data as your user id else 0 than you got only user id after that you easly pass it to another view

Comment: dude i alrady say that rigt now you recive response in that form  resid = 15; response = success; ok so insted of it you resive response in the form or userid and 0 means if success than user id other wise 0 and than directly pass your id to another view as i show in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

This is an `NSDictionary`. As with any `NSObject`, you can make it a property of source view controller and access it in another view controller.

Read it in detail: [Coordination between View Controllers.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary in the view controller you want to hold that data,while pushing that view controller you can take that data and use it.It is called as design patterns.

Comment: do you know parsing?? use NSJSONSerialization anf give nsdata object to that it will give you dictionary with key value pair.save it and send to other class using property.